# Getting error when I am trying to create bridge table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a museum database using PostgreSQL

I did all this work

```
CREATE DOMAIN lCap as int not null check ( VALUE >= 0 );
CREATE TYPE Cap as (min lCap, max lCap);
CREATE DOMAIN lDim as float8 not null check ( VALUE > 0 );
CREATE TYPE lArea as (length lDim, width lDim);
CREATE DOMAIN lNam as varchar(50) not null;
CREATE DOMAIN lDoor as smallint not null;

create table Locations
(
    locSerial       serial not null primary key,
    locName         lNam,
    locDimensions       lArea,
    locCapacity     Cap,
    locDoors        lDoor
);

CREATE DOMAIN eTime as timestamp not null;
CREATE DOMAIN eNam as varchar(25) not null;
CREATE DOMAIN eDescr as varchar(512) not null;

create table Exhibitions
(
   exhSerial            serial not null  primary key,
   exhName          eNam,
   exhDescription       eDescr,
   exhStrtDate          eTime,
   exhEndDate       eTime

);


CREATE DOMAIN tyID AS smallint not null check (VALUE > 100 );
CREATE DOMAIN tyNam AS varchar(20) not null;

CREATE TABLE Types(
    typID       tyID primary key,
    typName     tyNam

);


CREATE DOMAIN sID AS smallint not null check (VALUE > 100 );
CREATE DOMAIN sNam AS varchar(30) not null;

CREATE TABLE Subtypes(
    sbtID       sID PRIMARY KEY,
    sbtName     sNam


);


CREATE DOMAIN mID AS smallint not null check (VALUE > 100 );
CREATE DOMAIN mNam AS varchar(50) not null;

CREATE TABLE Mediums(
    medID       mID primary key,
    medName     mNam

);


CREATE DOMAIN crID AS smallint not null check (VALUE > 100 );
CREATE DOMAIN crNam AS varchar(35);

CREATE TABLE Creators(
    creID       crID primary key,
    creName     crNam

);


CREATE DOMAIN wAlphID AS varchar(4) not null;
CREATE DOMAIN wNumID AS smallint not null check (VALUE > 1000);
CREATE DOMAIN wObjNam AS varchar(120) not null;
CREATE DOMAIN wDateMad AS varchar(15) not null;
CREATE DOMAIN wDateAcqu AS date not null;
CREATE DOMAIN wInsurValue AS smallint not null;
CREATE DOMAIN wObjDiscip AS varchar(1000) not null;

CREATE TABLE Works(
   workAlphID           wAlphID,
   workNumberID     wNumID,
  workObjectName        wObjNam,
  workCreatorNameID     crID,
  workTypeID            tyID,
  workSubtypeID     sID,
  workDateMade      wDateMad,
  workDateOfAcquisition wDateAcqu,
   workInsuranceValue       wInsurValue,
   workObjectDiscription    wObjDiscip,
  primary key (workAlphID,workNumberID),
  foreign key (workCreatorNameID) references Creators(creID),
  foreign key (workTypeID) references Types(typID),
  foreign key (workSubtypeID) references Subtypes(sbtID)
);
```

Everything is okay up to this table

But when I am trying to create this table Works_Mediums as bridge between Works table and the mediums table

I keep getting this error 
ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "works"

```
CREATE TABLE Works_Mediums(         
   wmedAlphID      wAlphID, 
   wmedNumberID    wNumID,
   wmedID          mID,
   primary key (wmedAlphID, wmedNumberID, wmedID),
    foreign key (wmedAlphID) references Works(workAlphID),
    foreign key (wmedNumberID) references Works(workNumberID),
    foreign key (wmedID) references Mediums(medID)  
);
```

Any Ideas how to fix this error?

Regard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part

```
foreign key (wmedAlphID) references Works(workAlphID),
foreign key (wmedNumberID) references Works(workNumberID),
```

should be

```
foreign key (wmedAlphID, wmedNumberID) references Works (workAlphID, workNumberID),
```

PostgreSQL's error messages are excellent. In the table "Works", the unique constraint (a primary key constraint in this case) is on the pair of columns "workAlphID" and "workNumberID". Your foreign key constraint needs to reference *that pair*.

A unique constraint doesn't necessarily have to be a primary key constraint. Any set of columns declared `unique` can be the target of a foreign key constraint.